# Remove jQuery event where this is bound to the handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove a jQuery event who's callback is bound with `this`. The problem is that `.bind()` creates a new function every time... so when I try removing the event, it is technically not the same function so it doesn't work.

I can't figure out how to keep the right `this` inside the callback in this case:

```
class Controller {
    open() {
        $('body').on('click', this.handleClick.bind(this));
    }

    close() {
        $('body').off('click', this.handleClick.bind(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: just simply assign `this.handleClick.bind(this)` to another variable, then use that variable to bind event

Comment: you can just namespace your click event and .off the event w/ namespace like so: $('body').on('click.controller', ....); and $('body').off('click.controller');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use jQuery namespaces:

```
class Controller {
    open() {
        $('body').on('click.myNamespace', this.handleClick.bind(this));
    }

    close() {
        $('body').off('click.myNamespace');
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not an option, as I have other components relying on other events on the body. Doing this would remove all events.

Comment: Oh wait... name spacing would only remove that one?

Comment: @justinledouxweb Clarification: .off() with namespacing will remove ALL event handlers on the *specified element(s)* that match the *specified event* in the *specified namespace*. In the case that you only specify one handler, yes, it will only remove that one.

Comment: One issue with this approach is that a new function will be created each time `open()` is called, which, if `open()` is a function that gets called a lot, will have effect on the performance. If `open()` is called a couple times then it works as good as any other approach.

Answer (score 1):

Do the binding once in the constructor.

```
class Controller {

    constructor() {
      // overwrite handleClick() with its bound version
      this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    open() {
        $('body').on('click', this.handleClick);
    }

    close() {
        $('body').off('click', this.handleClick);
    }
}
```

This way you overwrite the function once with the bound version that refers to the proper `this` and then attach/detach that function in your methods.

The additional advantage of doing things this way is that **the binding is done only once**, during instantiation, and then any future calls to `open()` or `close()` will use the same function that has the proper `this`.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has its own `.bind` polyfill. You can use [`$.proxy()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to do what you want since it keep internaly a GUI. You can then unbind using the original function. jQuery is brillant enough:

```
class Controller {
    open() {
        $('body').on('click', $.proxy(this.handleClick, this));
    }

    close() {
        $('body').off('click', this.handleClick);
    }
}
```

Here an article that demonstrate it : http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2001-using-jquery-s-proxy-method-in-event-binding-and-unbinding.htm

> jQuery keeps an internal counter to represent a "guid" (Globally Unique ID). When a function goes through the proxy() method, jQuery generates a new guid value and then applies that guid to both the core function as well as the resultant proxy function. It does this so that you can use the original function reference to unbind an event handler callback that has been proxied - jQuery uses the guid to test for function equivalence during the unbind process.

To see it in action, just explore this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lfqq88uj/1/

Comment: One thing that might be worth noting is that this will create a new function each time `open` is called, which could be a performance bottleneck if open gets called a bunch of times (for each re-render for instance).